# Doctrine2 / PostgreSQL - Selection error with a nullable relation

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In my ZF2 application, I have 2 Doctrine2 entities : `Product` and `Partner`

Because in some cases a product doesn't need a partner, there is a nullable ManyToOne relation between Product and Partner.

It works if a partner is provided in the form (dropdown).
But if not, I have this error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.title AS title2 FROM partners t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [""]:

SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`
```

The entities :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 */
class Product extends AbstractEntity
{
    /* ... */

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Partner", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="partner_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $partner;

    /* ... */

    /**
     * @return Partner
     */
    public function getPartner()
    {
        return $this->partner;
    }

    /**
     * @param Partner $partner
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPartner(Partner $partner)
    {
        $this->partner = $partner;

        return $this;
    }

    /* ... */
}



/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="partners")
 */
class Partner extends AbstractEntity
{
    /* ... */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="partner", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"})
     **/
    protected $products;

    /* ... */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /* ... */

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;
        $product->setPartner($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $products
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addProducts($products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            $this->addProduct($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param null $products
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeProducts($products = null)
    {
        if (!$products)
        {
            $products = $this->getProducts();
        }

        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            if (is_object($product))
            {
                $this->products->removeElement($product);
            }
            else $this->products->remove($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $products
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProducts($products)
    {
        $this->products = $products;

        return $this;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you add ToNull filter to your form? Because form will send empty character and you should change that with null.

Comment: @hkulekci, no, I didn't add it

Comment: I dont understand? Do you want add or not?  Do you want to get reaction? :)

Comment: Can you add this filter, i guess it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hkulekci for the answer.

I just updated my input filter from that :

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return [
        'partner' => ['required' => true],
        /* ... */
    ];
}
```

To that :

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return [
        'partner' => [
            'required' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'filters' => [
                ['name' => 'Null']
            ]
        ],
        /* ... */
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow a `null` value to be passed to the `setPartner` method

```
public function setPartner(Partner $partner = null)
{
    $this->partner = $partner;

    return $this;
}
```

Also, depending on your form hydrator, you will need to make sure that if no partner is selected the empty value should be converted to `null`.